# Error in tkz-euclide \tkzDefPoint with square roots

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, calc

I cannot make `sqrt(x)` work in `\tkzDefPoint`; I'm getting the error `! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }` in the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,{-sqrt(3)}){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(-0.7,{sqrt(3.51)}){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(-0.4,{-sqrt(3.84)}){D}
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I have figured out is that **calc** package seems to enable functions such as `sqrt` and `sin`, and it is generally better to use parentheses to cover `sqrt(x)` since the ending ')' can be misunderstood as ending the line.
But in this case, it seems like '{}' is making a problem, and I couldn't find a solution to this simple problem...

Comment: To clear up a couple of misunderstandings: You're not loading the `calc` *package*, you're loading the TikZ *library* named `calc`, and these are not the same. And you do *not* need to load that library to enable `sqrt`,`sin` etc. for TikZ, they are defined by the `pgf` math engine, which is loaded by TikZ. And for TikZ coordinates you will always need `{}` if your x- or y-coordinate contains `()`. `tkzDefPoint` behaves a bit differently though, it doesn't look like it uses the `pgf` math engine to parse the input at all, relying instead of `\FPeval` from the `fp` package.

Comment: (I suppose in some sense there is not much difference between a package and a library, but as there is a package on CTAN called [`calc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/calc?lang=en), loaded with `\usepackage{calc}`, and this has a very different purpose to the TikZ library `calc`  loaded with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`, it's probably good to be a bit accurate).

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up; I didn't properly check calc library separately.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit following a comment by Mike.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pgfmath` defines a `sqrt` function that can be used in coordinates, so for normal TikZ code that would work. `tkz-euclide` however uses the `fp` package to do calculations in `\tkzDefPoint`, and `fp` doesn't provide `sqrt`. As Mike mentioned in a comment, it does provide the more general `root` though, so you can use `root(2,3)` to get the square root of 3.

As an alternative, instead of using `\tkzDefPoint(<x>,<y>){<name>}`, you can use the TikZ macro `\coordinate (<name>) at (<x>,<y>);`. (They amount to the same thing in the end I think, after the evaluation of the x- and y-components by `fp`, a `\coordinate` is defined.)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}    
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,{-root(2,2)}){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(-0.7,{root(2,3.51)}){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(-0.4,{-root(2,3.84)}){D}
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){A}
    \coordinate (B) at (1,{-sqrt(3)});
    \coordinate (C) at (-0.7,{sqrt(3.51)});
    \coordinate (D) at (-0.4,{-sqrt(3.84)});
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,D D,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The `FP` package has `root`. So `\tkzDefPoint(1,-root(2,3)){B}` works too.

Comment: @Mike Ah, right, I didn’t spot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also migrate to PSTricks as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2)(2,2)
    \pnodes
        (2,0){A}
        (!1 3 sqrt neg){B}
        (!-.7 3.51 sqrt){C}
        (!-.4 3.84 sqrt neg){D}
    \pspolygon[linejoin=2](A)(B)(C)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]