# Calculate a coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tkz-collection, root

I could calculate the coordinate, sure but I want Latex to do it.
But it gives many errors and a wrong coordinate pC', (pC is correct), what do I forget?

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}     

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[small, bf, hang]{caption}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}%,
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,through, shapes, decorations}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.9, yscale=1.9]
                \tkzDefPoint({0.5, 0.5*root(2,2)}){pC};
                \tkzDefPoint({0.5 + 0.25*root(2,2)}, {0.5*root(2,2) + 0.125*root(2,2)}){pC'};
                \draw[thick,red] (pC) -> (pC') ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know this `root(2,2)` function, what is it? In which package did you find it? Your code is not a minimal example, you should delete all packages that are not necessary in this example.

Comment: @AndréC According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396274/121799), `root(2,2)` is actually a valid (or even "better") choice in tkz-euclide. It comes with the `FP` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were certain issues in your code. For instance, `\tkzDefPoint({0.5, 0.5*root(2,2)}){pC};` needs to become `\tkzDefPoint({0.5},{0.5*root(2,2)}){pC};` (I think), i.e. every coordinate entry has to have its own curly braces. Then I removed spaces in the second coordinate and all of a sudden the code ran through. However, I cannot tell which was the "critical" space. And I guess this discussion is somewhat related to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396274/121799), so I'd like to repeat Torbjørn's statement that you do not need `tkz-euclide` to define coordinates. Finally, `\draw[thick,red] (pC) -> (pC') ;` does not work, but `\draw[thick,red,->] (pC) -- (pC') ;` does. BTW, you load tons of stuff that is not relevant to the problem.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}     
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.9, yscale=1.9]
    \tkzDefPoint(0.5,{0.5*root(2,2)}){pC}
    \tkzDefPoint({0.5 + 0.25*root(2,2)},{0.5*root(2,2)+0.125*root(2,2)}){pC'};
    \draw[thick,red,->] (pC) -- (pC') ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.9, yscale=1.9]
    \path (0.5,{0.5*sqrt(2)}) coordinate (pC)
    ({0.5 + 0.25*sqrt(2)},{0.5*sqrt(2)+0.125*sqrt(2)}) coordinate (pC');
    \draw[thick,red,->] (pC) -- (pC') ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]